# Algorithm: constrained XOR of numbers within a range

Tags: algorithm, xor

Let us say we are given a number n.
We need to find the number of values S ^ (S+n) lying in the range [L, R].
(Where S is any non-negative integer and ^ is the bitwise xor operator).

I can easily do this if n is power of two (they have a very useful pattern)

I am not sure how to solve this for any general n.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

n is also a non-negative integer.
n, L, R are all less than 10^18.

This was a programming question in some practice test which i gave sometime back, i just remembered this seeing a similar question in StackOverflow today.

**EDIT 2**:
Explaining with an example,
say n = 1.
Then we know that S ^ (S + 1) will always have a binary representation of all ones. eg: 1,3,7,...

So solving this is easy we just have to count the number of such numbers within the Range [L,R] it is quite simple.

For n = any power of 2 similar methods work. But i have no idea what to do if n is not a power of 2.

Comment: could you give an example

Comment: Is `n` also a non-negative integer?

Comment: Are there any additional constraints regarding L, R and n? What is the context of your question?

Comment: I edited the question to address all of your issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `C(n)` be the (infinite) set of numbers that can be written as `S ^ (S + n)` for some `S`.

We have the following recurrence relations on the sets `C(n)`:

- If `n = 2k` is even, then `C(n) = {2x : x in C(k)}`;
- If `n = 2k + 1` is odd, then `C(n) = {2x + 1 : x in C(k)} union {2x + 1 : x in C(k + 1)}`.

An algorithm can be deduced from these relations. More precisely, a pair `(C(n), C(n + 1))` can be deduced from `(C(n / 2), C(n / 2 + 1))`. Note that the `union` above is really a disjoint union, because every element in `C(n)` has the same parity as `n`, hence `C(k)` and `C(k + 1)` do not intersect.

---

Proof of the recurrence relations:

Simply look at the last binary digits of `n` and `S`.

Comment: Nice! thanks, now all i have to do is restrict the range, shouldn't be that big of a problem!!